# Cmd+Click in iTerm2 doesn't work for TypeScript error output

Tags: typescript, iterm2, tsc

The file name in the output looks like this:

```
path/filename/ext(line,col)
```

instead of the usual

```
path/filename/ext:line
```

so iTerm2 gives an error message instead of opening the file:

> There is no application set to open the URL :.

I'd be interested in a solution where tsc compiler has a standard output OR iTerm can understand this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a Smart Selection Rule as `(.+)\((\d+),(\d+)\): error TS(\d)+`.